# Calulation Formula from string to result

Tags: python, string, pandas, calculation

I have a columns string column like this:

```
A
'(1+2)'
'1*(1/2)'
'5*2'
```

How is it possible to solve these calculation as a float or integer?

```
calc_df['A'] = calc_df['A'].astype('Float64')
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(1+2)'

Comment: You could remove the quotes and use [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it.

```
import pandas as pd
A = ['(1+2)','1*(1/2)','5*2']
df = pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['A'])
pd.eval(df.A)

Result:  [3, 0.5, 10]
```